# How are these two sockets read correctly (no code)?

Tags: sockets

I have no code posted here because I'm trying to understand it on a simple example first, I hope this is okay.
Let's say there are packets `A, B, C, D` and `E` sent within a network (with established connections).
Packets `A, B, C` use TCP as transport protocol and `D, E` use UDP.

```
A: Has source-IP S1 , destination-IP D1 , source-port SP1 , destination-port DP1 , data: hello , seq number 100
B: Has source-IP S1 , destination-IP D1 , source-port SP1 , destination-port DP1 , data: myname , seq number 105
C: Has source-IP S9 , destination-IP D9 , source-port SP9 , destination-port DP9 , data: is , seq number 105
D: Has source-IP S3 , destination-IP D3 , source-port SP3 , destination-port DP3 , data: kath
E: Has source-IP S8 , destination-IP D3 , source-port SP8 , destination-port DP3 , data: elk
```

Packets `A` and `B` will use the same TCP socket (because they have same source ip, destination ip, source port, destination port).
Packet `C` will use a another TCP socket for its own,
Packets `D` and `E` will use the same UDP socket (because they have the same destination ip and destination port).

To make this example more simple, let's assume socket receive buffers are empty and we don't know if the sockets are all on the same computer.

Now if an application makes its first reading access on the socket which receives the first packets, what data would be read?

If we for example take the TCP socket for the packets `A, B`, then we would just get: `hellomyname` , right?

And if we take the UDP socket for the packets `D, E` , we should get `kathelk`.
I hope my example makes some sense, would it be correct like that?

Comment: "Now if an application makes its first reading access on the socket which receives the first packets, what data would be read?" You say "the socket", but your example has several sockets. Which socket is the application reading?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ohh right thank you, I mean that socket for the packets A and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends when the application attempts to read and which socket it attempts to read on. It also depends on how large a buffer the application provides when it attempts to read on the socket and what options the applications has specified for the read operation.

But generally:

A read on a TCP socket will get however much data is currently available to be read on that TCP connection, up to the buffer size the application provided. If no data is available, the operation will block until at least one byte is available.

A read operation on a UDP socket will get the first unread datagram if the buffer size is large enough to accommodate it. If no unread datagrams are available at that time, it will block until at least one datagram is received.

So, a read on the TCP connection will block if issued before the first packet is received, will get "hello " if after the first, and "hello myname " if after the second, and so on.

A read on the UDP socket will block if issued before the fourth packet is received and will get the "kath" datagram otherwise.

Comment: @kathelk UDP is a datagram protocol. It presents datagrams to the next layer. It's not clear from your question if the two packets are fragments of the same datagram or not, but I'm assuming they're not.